# How do I make my elements keep their proportions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have little boxes on my website that I can select. There is an icon from Font-Awesome on the top and my text in the bottom.
When I have it in full screen, it works well. When I have it on mobile size, it works well. When I am between these two, it's an absolute mess.

Is there a way that I can keep these elements at the same position and with the same proportions. So the text is always at x% from the bottom and take the same % of place on all view size and same thing from the icon.

These are pictures of the desktop version, mobile version and then the mess in between.
[image: bad]
[image: good]
[image: good]

```css
.interest-box {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid white;
}

.interest-box-adjuster {
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.interest-box-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.interest-box-content .interest-icon {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%, -50%);
}

.interest-box-activated {
  color: #0375B4;
  background-color: white;
}

.interest-box-activated .activated-icon {
  color: #0375B4;
}

.activated-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: transparent;
}

.interest-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .register-form {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .register-form p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .register-form input {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .register-form input[type=date] {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .register-form input[type=password] {
    border: 6px solid white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .interest-box-content .interest-icon {
    font-size: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="column is-one-fifth-desktop is-half-touch">
  <div className="interest-box">
    <div className="interest-box-adjuster">
      <div ref={"interest_box_content"} className={"interest-box-content" + (this.state.activated==t rue ? 'interest-box-activated' : '')} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <i ref={"interest_icon"} className={"interest-icon fas" + this.props.icon}></i>
        <i className="activated-icon fas fa-check"></i>
        <span className="interest-text is-size-3 is-size-4-mobile">Sports</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ref={"interest_box_content"}` is also some kind of framework you could tag this question with, right?

Comment: I tried to see if SASS corresponded but I realized it didn’t. It stayed in the bar and I thought it would be dismissed. Can you show me how to remove it ? I have only been there for a little bit of time.

Comment: Try to use flex

Comment: @Awais this would solve my position problem, but I still have an issue for the icon and the text...

Comment: @AsteroidSnowsuit Ok try to use `align-content` or `align-item` property on flex childs

Comment: @Awais i was talking about the size of the elements but thank you !

Comment: Ok if you need more help just let me know regarding to size of elements

Comment: @Awais well, do you have any idea how I can keep the proportion of the size of the elements. So if the icons take 50% of the box, I want it to take 50% of the box whether its on mobile, desktop or any screen.

Comment: @AsteroidSnowsuit Is your code update ?